# Let L(R) be the set of all right (left) ideals in a ring R. Show that L(R) is a modular lattice .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let L(R) be the set of all right (left) ideals in a ring R. Show that L(R) is a modular lattice .Give an example to show that the lattice L(R) need not be distributed.

Let $A, B, C \in L(R)$, 
I should try that $A \vee (B\wedge C)= (A\vee B)\wedge C$, but I do not understand why can this be possible as A, B and C are sets. This could not be better proving that $A\cup(B\cap C)= (A\cup B)\cap C$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supremum of two right ideals is their sum, as the union is not generally a right ideal.

It's quite easy to show that $L(R)$ is a lattice under
$$
A\land B=A\cap B,\qquad A\lor B=A+B
$$
when the order relation is set inclusion.

The modular property is

> if $C\subseteq B$, then $C+(A\cap B)=(C+A)\cap B$, for all $A\in L(R)$.

Suppose $c\in C$ and $x\in A\cap B$; then $c+x\in C+A$ and $c+x\in B$, so $c+x\in (C+A)\cap B$. Conversely, if $c\in C$, $a\in A$ and $b=c+a\in B$, then $a=b-c\in B$ due to $C\subseteq B$; therefore $c+a\in C+(A\cap B)$.

Comment: And give an example to show that the lattice L(R) need not be distributed?

Comment: @Nash A noetherian domain has a distributive lattice of ideals if and only if it is Dedekind. So $k[x,y]$ ($k$ a field) is a counterexample.

Comment: @nash the left ideals of $M_2(F_2)$ is another, perhaps more elementary example. It has exactly five left ideals forming the lattice $M_3$, which indicates it is nondistributive.